# Probabilities depending on date of last use

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a set of N questions. Every day I use one question, and I'd like to have a neat random selection:

- The first day, each question should have a probability of 1/N to be selected.
- Then, during the first month, every questions already used will not be used. Hence, the remaining question would all have a probably on 1/(N-number of questions already used) to be picked.
- Until now this is easy. But, starting the second month, I'd love to add back the questions which were used more than 30 days ago. But those questions should have less probability of getting picked than the one which were never picked, and the questions used the most time ago should have a bigger probability than questions which were used only 30 days ago. To summarize the order of probability:

`1 > p(questions never used) > p(oldest question used) > p(second oldest question used) > ... > p(question used 30 days ago) > 0`

with `p(questions never used)` being the same for all never used questions.

- The question used more than one year ago would be considered as never used. I could run out of questions never used before 1 year.
- Of course, all the numbers I gave (one question per day, reused after 1 month, same as never used after one year) and the probabilistic distribution can be changed.

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough, my probabilities lessons are far behind me.
Is there a formula or an algorithm to do that?

Comment: The algorithm is the set of rules you have written. But you will have to make those probabilities more certain for questions returned to the bank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively simple way to do this would be to draw the questions from a (probably virtual) hat in which you put one slip of paper for each question each day. If a question is used, you remove all its slips and only start putting new ones in again after $30$ days. Then the probability for a question to be drawn would be proportional to the number of corresponding slips. If this is too quick of an increase, you could reduce it by adding another slip for a question only every couple of days. A nice feature of this approach is that it’s self-normalizing. Whereas if you had some real-valued formula to produce these probablities, you’d have to add them all up and divide them by the sum to normalize their sum to $1$. The slips take care of that themselves; each one is equally likely to be picked (though of course if you do the draw virtually, you do have to know the total number of slips to generate an appropriate pseudorandom number).